# How to use Interceptor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Does anyone know how to handle this exception? In my Flutter app, this exception occurred on every page when I moved to the previous page without closing the expandable section/flush bar /Snackbar, etc of the current page. Even sometimes (debug lock !=true) occurred on screen.

```
 Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: 
 line 1973 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.
```

Is there any techniques through which I can handle all types of Exception in Flutter,  like Interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

you can try setting `Flutter.onError` in your main function before running app.

```dart
void main(){
    FlutterError.onError = (error){
       //if flutter framework catches an error. this callback will be called
       // handle the error here
    };
    
    runApp(App());
}
```